# Circular Knob html component won't rotate correctly with mouse

Tags: javascript, html, rotation

I am trying to get the center knob to rotate with mouse correctly, it's working but it seems to not align with mouse and jumps from side to side. What am i doing wrong?

Calculation:

```
this.angle = Math.atan2((e.clientX - this.center.x), (e.clientY - this.center.y) )*(270 / Math.PI);  
this.knob.style.transform = `rotate(${this.angle}deg)`;
```

Demo:
https://replit.com/@Nashorn1/RotateKnob#index.html

Comment: Please add your code to the question

Comment: The demo link shows the code and can be forked and edited and reshared

Comment: If that demo is deleted then this question becomes invalid.

Comment: Have you tried it? I dont plan on deleting

Comment: Yes, I did try and observed the glitch/jump behaviour you mentioned. I have not cloned the project to try though.